# How many overrides can be in the to string method of custom classes?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make a couple of overrides for `ToString()` method in class instead of one?

I have a project, that would use `ToString()` method, depends on the result set of searching.

Comment: You can only have one override of `.ToString()`. Do you mean overloads?

Comment: Only one from `object`. But you can define any method you want like: `ToString()` - `ToString(bool full)` - `ToString(MyEnum gender)` ... Only the first is overrided from `object` unless an ancestor have some special. Also you can for example define: `ToStringHumanized()` - `ToStringShort()` - `ToStringFiltered(MyEnum gender)` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Overloads have to differ in signature, and in this case there's nothing to vary because the function doesn't have any arguments.

If you had more than one identical `toString` function, how would the compiler know which one you intended to call?

Comment: "Overrides have to differ in signature"- I think you mean *overloads*. (When *overriding*, the signature has to match the method you're overriding...)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to make a couple of overrides for `ToString()` method in class instead of one?

It depends

You either mean "overloads" in which case, sure - make as many variations of a method as you want but they have to have different signatures (some unique combination of number of/type of/order of types of arguments)

Or you really do mean "overrides" in which case you can only do it if there is a suitable method in a base class to override. If your class descends from object then no; object has only one overridable `ToString`. You could overload other variations of `ToString` but they wouldn't be overrides